# Mocha web socket testing for https server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, https, mocha.js

I've been trying to test a web socket connection. There a few good tutorials out there that describe it which led me to this sort of dummy code just to see if I can test data being sent over websockets:

```
var socketURL= 'https://localhost:9002';
var io = require('socket.io-client');
options={
transports: ['websocket'],
'force new connection': true
};
describe("Connection test", function(){
it('to check if data is received',function(done){
    var client = io.connect(socketURL,options);

    client.on('connect',function(){
        console.log("in connect");
        client.emit('data',{data:10});

        client.on('result',function(data){
            console.log(data);
            data.should.equal(10);
            done();
        });

    });
});
```

I've set up the server like so, where the OPTIONS determine the key and cert to read

```
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(OPTIONS, app);

httpsServer.listen(9002);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        socket.emit('result',data);
    })
})
```

The problem is that the client.on('connect') is never called, I can see this by nothing printing out to the console. All that happens is a time out error: "timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test."
I've moved the done() and it doesn't make a diffence. I think the problem is that the tutorials I've follow use a http server whereas I'm using a https server, and I figure that this may require addition methods to connect, however I'm quite new to mocha so I don't know what they may be.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you using self-signed certificates?  If so, running your code like this:

```
 env DEBUG=* mocha test/example.js
```

gives the following error:

```
Mon, 04 Jul 2016 11:22:20 GMT engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":{"code":"UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE","type":"error","target":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":4,"_socket":null,"_ultron":null,"_closeReceived":false,"bytesReceived":0,"readyState":0,"supports":{"binary":true},"extensions":{},"_isServer":false,"url":"wss://localhost:9002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket","protocolVersion":13,"binaryType":"buffer"}}}
```

Note the **UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE**

So, add the certificate authority to the client options, e.g.

```
options={
ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'certs', 'client', 'my-root-ca.crt.pem')),
transports: ['websocket'],
'force new connection': true
};
```

fix

```
    data.data.should.equal(10);
```

and your test passes:

```
  Connection test
in connect
{ data: 10 }
    √ to check if data is received (68ms)


  1 passing (75ms)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pass done in mocha test case, by default timeout period is 2000ms (2 seconds). It needs more time to connect to your web socket connection.

The given error  **time out error: "timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.**

Problem should be fixed with the following code :

```
it('to check if data is received',function(done){

    this.timeout(60000);  // 60 seconds
    var client = io.connect(socketURL,options);

    client.on('connect',function(){
        console.log("in connect");
        client.emit('data',{data:10});

        client.on('result',function(data){
            console.log(data);
            data.should.equal(10);
            done();
        });

    });
});
```

this.timeout(60000) tells mocha to wait 60 seconds to complete the test case.